# Display database row inside html using php

Tags: php, css, html, mysqli

Im trying to display the database rows in html using php.

here is my php code thats working:

```
while($traveller=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

        echo "<tbody>";

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td border = 3px solid #555555 padding = 5px 10px >". $traveller['ticket_no'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['fname'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['lname'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['flight_name'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['d_name'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['plane_name'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['boarding_time'] ." </td>";

        echo "<td>". $traveller['depart_time'] ." </td>";

        echo "</tbody>";

        echo "</tr>";


    }
```

But its black and white.
im trying to add some style to it so im trying to link it between my html table but its not working and im not sure what the problem is. here is the code:

```
<td> <?php echo "$traveller['ticket_no']"; ?></td>
```

is there a way to solve this or add styles to the table.

any help is acceptable and appreaciated.

Comment: use with style tag within td , like this <td style="border:1px">

Comment: Add your styles inside style="" attribute in elements. You just add your style in elements which cannot be recognised by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use style tag inside 
example:

```
<td class='myclass'>

<style>
td.myclass
{
  text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this because you missed style attribute.

```
<?php
while($traveller=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){ ?>
    <tr>
       <td style="background-color: red;"><?php echo $traveller['ticket_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo$traveller['fname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['lname'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['flight_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['d_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['plane_name'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['boarding_time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $traveller['depart_time'];?></td>        
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give style to table,tr,td tags, then only you can add styles to table
like this:-

```
            <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            th, td {
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

            th {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
            }
            </style>
```

then when you print table it will display with specified styles,
here i'm giving styles to diect table, tr, td tags
if you want you can assign "class" to table,tr or td and give style to classes

as you want to give link in table, code like this:-

```
            <td><a href=""> <?php echo "$traveller['ticket_no']"; ?></a></td>
```

and there are fault's in the way you written the loop, just loop tr only 
don't include tbody or anything inside loop,it should be outside the loop like this:-

```
            echo "<tbody>";

            while($traveller=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['ticket_no'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['fname'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['lname'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['flight_name'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['d_name'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['plane_name'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['boarding_time'] ." </td>";

                echo "<td>". $traveller['depart_time'] ." </td>";

                echo "</tr>";


            }

            echo "</tbody>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try style in php code like this:

```
echo "<tbody>";
   while($traveller=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

    echo "<tr style='color:white;background-color:green'>";

    echo "<td style='border: 3px solid #555555;padding:5px 10px' >". $traveller['ticket_no'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['fname'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['lname'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['flight_name'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['d_name'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['plane_name'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['boarding_time'] ." </td>";

    echo "<td>". $traveller['depart_time'] ." </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
```

Or you can try style in html code :

```
<?php
 while($traveller=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){ ?>
<tr>
   <td style="border: 3px solid #555555;padding:5px 10px"><?php echo $traveller['ticket_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo$traveller['fname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['lname'];?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['flight_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['d_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['plane_name'];?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['boarding_time']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $traveller['depart_time'];?></td>        
</tr>
```